# How to phase sHift a sine wave in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I took 18 samples of a sine signal(Va) of frequency 50Hz and sampling frequency of 900Hz  using Matlab.
I want to phase shift the signal with 120 deg. where my result=Va*(e^j120).
As we know that multiplication of e^j120 will only phase shift the signal with 120' since its magnitude is 1.
I want that phase shifted sample here.
Please help me out how to do it using VHDL.

Comment: Can you find a simple integer relationship between your desired phase shift and your sample period? If you can, you have a very easy task.

Comment: If I use this: 360/120=3, 18/3=6.   so 6th sample is the 120 deg. phase shifted value?

Comment: One can use lookup table or divide 900/6 then divide by 2 on each each of 3 outputs with a sync. reset will keep phases in same order for 3 digital phases, or use 18 stage shift registers and detect every 6th bit out of 18 in a ring counter shift register in VHDL. It depends what output you need.  Analog, digital square wave , edge or sine out using PWM